Near errorless issue with VirtualBox and/or nfs
Server/host: DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
Server NFS-common version: nfs-common/jammy-updates,now 1:2.6.1-1ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
Server NFS-server: nfs-kernel-server/jammy-updates,now 1:2.6.1-1ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed]
Client/guest: DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 23.10"
Client NFS-common version: nfs-common/mantic,now 1:2.6.3-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]

I have a NAS setup and use my network share to run Virtualbox over my LAN. The system was configured some time ago. This issue popped up after a recent update.
When I launch a VM over LAN, it will start fine but after a short while things I click on will begin to disappear or not even load a profile. If it does load, after a short while of the client being left alone, the command line will start to produce i/o errors with any command I attempt on the CLI. It is behaving exactly like a drive going bad.
I have applied
fsck -y /dev/sda1

on client and host. It will find errors from within the client, but the host is error free.
Wireshark: [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): This frame is a (suspected) retransmission]

I do see a number of these retransmission from server on the wire but that's not telling me a whole lot.
The client will reply with
   [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): This frame is a (suspected) retransmission]

These are the only 2 questionable items in my VirtualBox log are:
VirtualBox logs: 09:33:52.177582 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_VM_ERROR (0x80bb0003) aIID={4680b2de-8690-11e9-b83d-5719e53cf1de} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={Could not take a screenshot (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-37

or
VirtualBox logs: In nested-guest hwvirt mode  = false

I found nothing in strace nor nfstrace on the server that would indicate any errors
Client will just start producing i/o errors. Which only tells me to look for a bad drive. I can't find one.
sudo nfstrace -v 2 -m live -f 'ip and port 2049' --analysis=/usr/lib/nfstrace/
libbreakdown.so
produces: Detect session 192.168.1.123:911 --> 192.168.1.111:2049(brad-Inspiron-3501:nfs) [TCP]
^C###  Breakdown analyzer  ###
CIFS v1 protocol: Data transmission has not been detected.
###  Breakdown analyzer  ###
CIFS v2 protocol: Data transmission has not been detected.
###  Breakdown analyzer  ###
NFS v3 protocol: Data transmission has not been detected.
###  Breakdown analyzer  ###
NFS v4.0 protocol: Data transmission has not been detected.
###  Breakdown analyzer  ###
NFS v4.1 protocol: Data transmission has not been detected.
Interrupted by user.
Statistics from interface: wlp0s20f3
  packets received by filtration: 29718
  packets dropped by kernel     : 0
  packets dropped by interface  : 0

I also got nfstrace to produce this. Not sure how.
RPC Call XID:4150270869 is not found for 192.168.1.123:727 --> 192.168.1.111:2049 [TCP] RPC Call XID:4183825301 is not found for 192.168.1.123:727 --> 192.168.1.111:2049 [TCP] RPC Call XID:4250934165 is not found for 192.168.1.123:727 --> 192.168.1.111:2049 [TCP] RPC Call XID:4217379733 is not found for 192.168.1.123:727 --> 192.168.1.111:2049 [TCP]

my nfsstat:
sudo nfsstat all
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badfmt     badauth    badclnt
1352976    0          0          0          0       

Server nfs v4:
null             compound         
1         0%     1353086  99%     

Server nfs v4 operations:
op0-unused       op1-unused       op2-future       access           close            
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     296       0%     248       0%     
commit           create           delegpurge       delegreturn      getattr          
1         0%     3         0%     0         0%     59        0%     32953     0%     
getfh            link             lock             lockt            locku            
158       0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     
lookup           lookup_root      nverify          open             openattr         
200       0%     0         0%     0         0%     280       0%     0         0%     
open_conf        open_dgrd        putfh            putpubfh         putrootfh        
0         0%     1         0%     1347589  33%     0         0%     16        0%     
read             readdir          readlink         remove           rename           
925303   22%     12        0%     0         0%     17        0%     186       0%     
renew            restorefh        savefh           secinfo          setattr          
0         0%     0         0%     187       0%     0         0%     12117     0%     
setcltid         setcltidconf     verify           write            rellockowner     
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     408012    9%     0         0%     
bc_ctl           bind_conn        exchange_id      create_ses       destroy_ses      
0         0%     5         0%     11        0%     24        0%     14        0%     
free_stateid     getdirdeleg      getdevinfo       getdevlist       layoutcommit     
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     
layoutget        layoutreturn     secinfononam     sequence         set_ssv          
0         0%     0         0%     1         0%     1353028  33%     0         0%     
test_stateid     want_deleg       destroy_clid     reclaim_comp     allocate         
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     10        0%     1         0%     
copy             copy_notify      deallocate       ioadvise         layouterror      
1         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     
layoutstats      offloadcancel    offloadstatus    readplus         seek             
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     
write_same       
0         0%

I have debug level logging enabled on the server and see all kinds of information flying through my syslogs. But no useful error is produced.
When I try to use the host as a desktop with everything as localhost, and not over LAN, the host and client run perfectly normally. If I start to use it over LAN, the services will degrade and crash.
I have the same issue as this guy.
https://www.reddit.com/r/freenas/comments/9t7k2n/nfs_performance_gradually_slows_the_longer_a/
I tried to install a brand spanking new VM and after a while and being left alone, it started to produce the same i/o errors at the CLI with any command.
Does anyone know of a tool I could use to get the system to make some coherent noise/error code on a degrading nfs connection? I can't find any relevant Bluez Cluez.
